# writing Umlaute to mariadb causes non-UTF-8-encoding

Tags: django, django-models, django-jsonfield

I am using mariadb with `Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)` and python `3.7.3` and for some reason beyond me, a CSV file read in and written to the database is saved in some weird encoding:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model)
    data        = models.JSONField()
    store       = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    number      = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

and when writing to the database with shell:

```
Product.objects.create(store = store, number = 123, data = {"direction": "süden"})
```

this reads in the database as:
`{"direction": "s\u00fcden"}`

but in my database the line reads as `"number": 123, "data": {"direction": "s\u00fcden"}`.

I already tried setting the an encoder for the JSONField:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
...
data = models.JSONField(encoder = DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

and then ran migrations again. A simple test can be done in the admin, when searching for products `süden` returns zero hits. But when manually altering the value to `süden` in the db that obviously works. Also, when searching for `123` in the admin, I see the word `süden` written correctly.

So my guess is, that I need to implement some kind of equivalent of pythons json `ensure_ascii = False` option?

Also I wrote the word `süden` to a `Charfield` which shows up correctly in the database, without any escapes/encoding errors.

Answer (score 1):

As this took me some while and I got some help in the django forum, I want to answer the question. I was not able to implement my own decoder, and I still would love to see how that works (very little examples around) but I managed to solve the task by overwriting `get_prep_value` of Django's `JSONField`:

```
class MyJSONField(models.JSONField):
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return json.dumps(value, ensure_ascii = False)
```

and therefore the `Product` model changes to:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    data   = MyJSONField()
    store  = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Migrations must be run again!

Answer (score 0):

`DjangoJSONEncoder` can be configured just by overriding the constructor as follows:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
        
class MyJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ensure_ascii = False
    
class Dummy(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField(encoder=MyJSONEncoder)
```